# Not too obsolete package extending the built-in functionality of Permutation Groups

Tags: packages, permutation, group-theory

Is there a modern package geared to permutation groups? With functions, for instance, for group-isomorphism (either w.r.t. permutation representation & w.r.t. group structure), direct, semidirect and indirect group-product, level of transitivity et.c.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function [FindGroupIsomorphism](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FindGroupIsomorphism) in the Wolfram Function Repository.